# How to tackle 'Unused private fields should be removed' in SonarQube + lombok?

Tags: sonarqube

Anything other than Deactivating the rule or adding entry in Exclusions/Issues? 
I'm using `@Data` annotation

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in version 2.8 of the Java Engine.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-73

Comment: above link cannot apply to `@Data` i guess.

Comment: Have you found a way to fix this issue ( could be replaced by a local variable ) ?.lombok getters and setters

Comment: @AbdulRazakAK I don't use Sonarqube anymore, but it sounds like it has been fixed for most relevant Lombok annotations - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-990